# Can someone help me with this extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What am I doing wrong here?

```
{
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "background": {
        "page": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "script.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
    "description": "XDA-Developers",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon128.png",
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png"
    },
    "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrsWIbSkVm2ikw4QDz79/25CcH+wA+zPdYwiFF/T19YqROUJwZEmmZAis3uLOCaX5GqirmcUoRRzp31OEWxW4AQVpkdDPfXbmi3ZAcdAz/qR+JarWq39nA7CBGcvn6G/g8Z3N9jOKU93fIp0L3eqecrCsk/OJb2sLVgr6f/XjBywIDAQAB",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Xda-Developers",
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation"
    ],
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "version": "0.3.1",
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "script.js",
}
```

I'm confused. I've used JSONlint but it's not helping me by saying "PARSE ERROR"

Answer (score 2):

You never closed the `[` for the array in the last few lines.

```
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "script.js",
}
```

Comment: And the comma after `"script"` should also be removed. JSON is quite simple, I suggest to read the small specification at http://json.org to avoid such errors in the future.